# Jetpack Compose how to draw dynamic line (chart)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I need to draw a graph that will scroll horizontally. The line is dynamically updated. I am having the following problems:

1. lineTo is very slow, and the data update rate is about 200ms
2. When scrolling the ChartCanvas is recomposed. This shouldn't happen.

How can I fix this or is there any other solution?

```
val spacing = 100f

    val upperValue = 10
    val lowerValue = -110
    val density = LocalDensity.current


    val textPaint = remember(density) {
        Paint().apply {
            color = android.graphics.Color.WHITE
            textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
            textSize = density.run { 12.sp.toPx() }
        }
    }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState(13)

    val min = scrollState.value/12.5
    val max  = min+105
    scrollCallback(min, max)

    Box() {
        Canvas(modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(20.dp)
            .background(Color.Black)) {
            Timber.i("canvas recompose")
            val priceStep = (upperValue - lowerValue) / 12f
            (0..12).forEach { i ->
                drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas.apply {
                    drawText(
                        round(lowerValue + priceStep * i).toString(),
                        30f,
                        size.height - spacing - i * size.height / 12f,
                        textPaint
                    )
                }
            }

        }

        Box(modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(scrollState)) {
            ChartCanvas(spacing = spacing, textPaint = textPaint, lowerValue = lowerValue, upperValue = upperValue)
        }
```

```
@Composable
fun ChartCanvas(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
                spacing : Float,
                textPaint : Paint,
                lowerValue : Int,
                upperValue : Int){

    Timber.i("ChartCanvas recompose")
    val vm: MainViewModel = MainViewModel.getInstance()
    val signalSeries = vm.arinstProvider?.signalSeries?.collectAsState()

    var data = signalSeries?.value ?:  emptyList()
    if (data.isEmpty()){
        data = (35..6000).map { Pair(it.toDouble(), Random.nextInt(-110, -10).toDouble()) }
    }

    val path = remember { Path() }


    Canvas(modifier = modifier
        .width(33400.dp)
        .height(400.dp)) {
        Timber.i("canvas recompose")
        val spacePerHour = 11
        (35..6000 step 35).forEach { i ->
            drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas.apply {
                drawText(
                    i.toString(),
                    spacing + i * spacePerHour,
                    size.height,
                    textPaint
                )
            }
        }
        path.reset()

        path.apply {
            val height = size.height
            val sortedData = data.sortedBy { it.first }
            sortedData.indices.forEach { i ->
                val firstRatio = (sortedData[i].second - lowerValue) / (upperValue - lowerValue)

                val x1 = (spacing + sortedData[i].first * spacePerHour).toFloat()
                val y1 = height - spacing - (firstRatio * height).toFloat()

                if (i == 0) {
                    moveTo(x1, y1)
                }

                Timber.i("line To x ${x1} y ${y1} ")
                lineTo(x1, y1)

            }
        }
        Timber.i("draw path ${path}")
        drawPath(
            path = path,
            color = Color.White,
            style = Stroke(
                width = 1.dp.toPx()
            )
        )
    }
}
```

I tried to render the canvas separately, it didn't help, I also tried to use compose libraries, but they don't work for me

Comment: seems you need a  continuous horizontal graph. you could use a this https://medium.com/@shevach/path-along-recyclerview-59780076198f and use LazyRow to get your required graph

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MPAndroidCharts is a powerful and popular chart library for Android. It supports a wide variety of charts, including line charts, bar charts, pie charts, and radar charts.

MPAndroidCharts is that it is not Jetpack Compose compliant. However, this is not a major issue, as Jetpack Compose allows you to use good-old Android views. This means that you can still use MPAndroidCharts in your Jetpack Compose projects, by using the **AndroidView** composable.

Here is an example of how to use the AndroidView composable to display a line chart in a Jetpack Compose project:

```
AndroidView(factory = { ctx ->
  com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart(ctx).apply {
    // Set properties until
  }
})
```

This code will create a line chart and display it in the current composable. The LineChart class is from the MPAndroidCharts library. You can use this class to set the properties of the chart, such as the data that it displays, the colors that it uses, and the title that it shows.

For more information on how to use MPAndroidCharts in Jetpack Compose, please refer to the MPAndroidCharts documentation: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart